# list comprehension, how to append the new elements to the list?

Tags: python, list

am working on my Python assessment and I need a hand :(
so, the task is to use this equation: 10*x-5 and print positive numbers only; the task focuses on using list comprehension, finally, I've to print the updated list. I did all of that but i couldn't figure out how to insert/append the updated elements to the new list, so here is what've done..

```
lst =[]
Update_MyList = [lst.append(MyList[z])for z in range(len(MyList)) if (10*MyList[z]-5 > 0)]
Update_MyList.append(lst)
print(Update_MyList)
```

all what I get is:[None, None, None, None, None]

Comment: [How to use List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: Why are you appending to a new list when list comprehension is itself creating a list? Also, ```.append()``` returns ```None```

Comment: Get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list))`. Use `for item in list`

Comment: You're confusing list comprehensions with `for` loops.

Comment: @Sujay the task is ". Update your list to get a new list that its values follow the equation:
(10*x-5) where x is the values of your original list, and the new list should
contain only positive values. (you must use list comprehension method for
this part) "

Comment: Are the x values needed for 10*x-5 supposed to be taken from `MyList`?

Comment: ```lst.append(MyList[z])``` returns ```None```. What do you expect from it

Comment: @TomKarzes the task is "Update your list to get a new list that its values follow the equation: (10*x-5) where x is the values of your original list, and the new list should contain only positive values. (you must use list comprehension method for this part) "

Comment: @Sujay idk :) am just a beginner

Comment: Reading the problem description, I don't think they want you to replace negative values with `None` in the result list.  I also don't think they'll like it if you evaluate the function 10*x-5 more than once per value.

Comment: @TomKarzes , yes Tom i couldn't deliver the question correctly, sorry for that :(  I posted the correct answer :) thank you for your efforts you taught me something new!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Code1

Assuming your MyList is [1, -2, 3] and you want to print None when output is negative. Here's a code1:

```
MyList = [1, -2, 3]

Update_MyList = [10*x-5 if (10*x-5 > 0) else None for x in MyList]

print(Update_MyList)
```

Output:

```
[5, None, 25]
```

---

### After Edit

---

### Code 2

If you don't want `None` for negative values, just remove `else None` part. Here's a code2:

```
MyList = [1, -2, 3]

Update_MyList = [10*x-5 if (10*x-5 > 0) for x in MyList]

print(Update_MyList)
```

Output:

```
[5, 25]
```

---

### Code 3

If you are using python>=3.8, use the below code to avoid calculating 10*x-5 twice. Here's a code3:

```
MyList = [1, -2, 3]

Update_MyList = [y for x in MyList if (y := 10*x-5) > 0]

print(Update_MyList)
```

Output:

```
[5, 25]
```

Comment: You shouldn't evaliate 10*x-5 more than once per list value.  See my answer for the right way to do this.  This also retains `None` in the list, which is contrary to the problem statement.

Comment: I understand that evaluating 10*x-5 twice is not the best choice, but if we don't do that we get the problem of a double loop. So I guess it would be a trade-off. For the `None`, I agree with you. I should remove `else None`.

Comment: Right, I used two loops to do it, but they aren't nested.  The other way is to filter based on the original `MyList` value, which works in this case but is specific to the function 10*x-5, so I really don't like doing it that way.

Comment: Thanks to your comment I found a way to write it in a single loop and single evaluation of 10*x-5. I added it in Code3 of my answer. (for python 3.8)

Comment: Note that `(y :=10*x-5 ) and (y > 0)` is equivalent to `(y :=10*x-5) > 0`.  There's no need for the `and`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simplest way to do this using list comprehensions.  First, create the function values:

```
MyList1 = [10*x-5 for x in MyList]
```

Then filter out the negative values:

```
MyList2 = [v for v in Mylist1 if v >= 0]
```

Here i've retained the zero values, but you can exclude them as well by changing `v >= 0` to `v > 0`.

This works fine as it is, although you can combine them if you wish.  You obviously don't want to evaluate 10*x-5 more than once per value, but you can create `MyList2` directly as follows:

```
MyList2 = [v for v in (10*x-5 for x in MyList) if v >= 0]
```

This basically combines the two, with the first now being left as a generator that is never expanded into an actual list.  Again, the function 10*x-5 is never evaluated more than once per original list value.  And again, you can use `v >= 0` or `v > 0` depending on whether you want to include or exclude zero.

If you're willing to make the filter condition dependent on the specific function 10*x-5, you can do:

```
MyList2 = [v for x, v in enumerate(MyList) if v >= 0.5]
```

This will work with floating point values such as 0.1, 0.6, etc.  If you want to exclude zero, you can use `v > 0.5`.  I actually don't like this solution as well as the previous one though, since (1) it's very specific to the function 10*x-5, and (2) it's using floating point, which is safe with 0.5 but generally not something you want to use for exact comparisons.

Comment: Thank you mate!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! You saved me!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

So i figured this out :)

```
Update_MyList = [10*MyList[z]-5 for z in range(len(MyList)) if (MyList[z] > 0)]
print(Update_MyList)
```

Comment: I've added several alternate solutions to my original answer, including one that's essentially the same as what you're doing here except that it works for values like 0.1 and 0.6.  It also uses `enumerate`, which is better in situations like this.  But I like my second-to-last solution better, since (1) it's not specific to the function 10*x-5 and (2) it doesn't use floating point comparisons.